# Query to find result with max rundate with max horizon

Tags: mysql, sql, max

Table data looks like:

```
EventID | MPID | rundate     | Horizon | otherData 
1       | 1    | 23-Jun-2014 | 360     | other value
1       | 1    | 23-Jun-2014 | 365     | pther value 
1       | 1    | 23-Jun-2014 | 300     | pther value 
1       | 1    | 22-Jun-2014 | 700     | pther value 
1       | 2    | 23-Jun-2014 | 400     | other value
1       | 2    | 23-Jun-2014 | 340     | oth
2       | 3    | 23-Jun-2014 | 360     | pther value 
2       | 3    | 23-Jun-2014 | 300     | pther value 
2       | 3    | 22-Jun-2014 | 365     | pther value
```

I want to select the max rundate for each event and marketplace group and then select max horizon among that group and then print the entire row.

Desired Result is :

```
EventID | MPID | rundate     | Horizon | otherData 
1       | 1    | 23-Jun-2014 | 365     | pther value 
1       | 2    | 23-Jun-2014 | 400     | other value
2       | 3    | 23-Jun-2014 | 360     | pther value
```

Please let me know the SQL query for this.

I tried following query but its not working:

```
SELECT * from dsie_result_overalls where id in (
SELECT k.id from dsie_result_overalls k,
(
SELECT a.event_id, a.marketplaceid, MAX(a.horizon) as horizon FROM dsie_result_overalls a,
(
    SELECT id, event_id, marketplaceid, MAX(rundate) AS rundate FROM dsie_result_overalls
    GROUP BY event_id, marketplaceid
) b
WHERE a.event_id = b.event_id AND a.marketplaceid = b.marketplaceid AND a.rundate = b.rundate
GROUP BY a.event_id, a.marketplaceid
    ) l WHERE k.event_id = l.event_id AND k.marketplaceid = l.marketplaceid AND k.horizon  =    l.horizon
);
```

It selects the multiple rundate for max horizon.

Comment: Your example shows a 1-to-1 relationship between events and mpids. Is this right? Also, and not unrelated, what is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: No i have updated the example. I have an ID columns which Auto increment is my primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
Select T.* From Tbl T JOIN
   ( Select Max(S.Horizon) MaxHorizon,Max(S.rundate) As dte,S.EventID,S.MPID
     From Tbl S Join
        ( Select T1.EventID,Max(T1.rundate) As Maxrundate,T1.MPID
          From Tbl T1 Group By T1.EventID,T1.MPID
        ) JR On S.rundate = JR.Maxrundate AND S.EventID = JR.EventID AND S.MPID = JR.MPID
        Group By S.MPID,S.EventID
   )R ON T.Horizon = R.MaxHorizon AND T.EventID = R.EventID AND T.MPID = R.MPID AND T.rundate = R.dte
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ebc5/7)**

---

Output would be

---

```
EventID | MPID | rundate     | Horizon | otherData 
1       | 1    | 23-Jun-2014 | 365     | pther value 
1       | 2    | 23-Jun-2014 | 400     | other value
2       | 3    | 23-Jun-2014 | 360     | pther value
```

Comment: I was also modifying my existing query. I also came up with similar looking solution. Looks good to me . Thanks!

Comment: I think this solution is flawed. What if you add another row (1,1,'2014-06-21',365,'bar')?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by event and marketplace an get the MAX(rundate). The MAX(horizon) you can get follow.

```
SELECT eventid
     , mpid
     , MAX(rundate) rundate
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(horizon ORDER BY rundate DESC, horizon DESC),',',1) horizon 
  FROM dsie_result_overalls 
 GROUP  
    BY eventid
     , mpid
```

Comment: I didn't get can you write full query. I am using mysql

Comment: SELECT 
      event_id, 
      marketplaceid,
      MAX(rundate) AS rundate,
      substring_index(
        group_concate(`horizon` ORDER BY rundate DESC, horizon DESC),
        ',',
        1
      ) AS horizon  
    FROM dsie_result_overalls
    GROUP BY event_id, marketplaceid

Comment: I don't know what you will do with `otherData` and I can't find `id` in your table structure.

Comment: Nice idea but note that, without some adjustment, this will grab the wrong ids (the id PK was added as a later amendment to the original question)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM dsie_result_overalls x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT a.eventid 
            , a.mpid
            , a.rundate
            , MAX(a.horizon) max_horizon
         FROM dsie_result_overalls a
         JOIN
            ( SELECT eventid
                   , mpid
                   , MAX(rundate) max_rundate
                FROM dsie_result_overalls
               GROUP
                  BY eventid
                   , mpid
            ) b
           ON b.eventid = a.eventid
          AND b.mpid = a.mpid
          AND b.max_rundate = a.rundate
        GROUP
           BY a.eventid
            , a.mpid
            , a.rundate
     ) y
    ON y.eventid = x.eventid
   AND y.mpid = x.mpid
   AND y.rundate = x.rundate
   AND y.max_horizon = x.horizon;
```

The hack way...

```
SELECT *  
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM dsie_result_overalls 
        ORDER 
           BY eventid
            , mpid
            , rundate DESC
            , horizon DESC
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY eventid
     , mpid;
```

The old-fashioned way...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM dsie_result_overalls x
  LEFT 
  JOIN dsie_result_overalls y 
    ON y.eventid = x.eventid 
   AND y.mpid = x.mpid 
   AND (y.rundate > x.rundate OR (y.rundate = x.rundate AND y.horizon > x.horizon)) 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```